# In Blender 3.2 can't find the swiftBlock menu after installation

Tags: add-on

I have installed `blender` on `Ubuntu 20` via the command `sudo snap install blender --classic`.

Also I have followed the instructions about the installation of `swiftBlock` [here](https://github.com/flowkersma/swiftBlock). Also, I correctly inserted the addon via the menu *Edit > Preferences > addons*. But where is the *swiftBlock* menu? I can't see it.

Comment: It looks as if that (third-party) addon was last updated around 3 years ago so it's unlikely to work with recent versions of Blender. The Blender version in the init code is version 2.7.7 by the look of it. Best to try to contact the author directly if he/she is still around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem in this way. I have installed `blender 2.82` via `apt install blender` command. Then I have followed thew guide in https://swiftblock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swift.html#installation-and-start-up to install swiftBlock for blender 2.82.

Comment: Note that this is not the same repository as linked in the question, it's a fork that was updated so that it works in newer versions.

Answer (score 5):

The add-on was developed for Blender 2.77 as indicated by the `bl_info` in the `_init_.py` file.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "SwiftBlock",
    "author": "Karl-Johan Nogenmyr, Mikko Folkersma, Turo Valikangas",
    "version": (0, 2),
    "blender": (2, 7, 7),
    "location": "View_3D > Object > SwiftBlock",
    "description": "Writes block geometry as blockMeshDict file",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/SwiftBlock",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "OpenFOAM"}
```

Due to [changes in the Python API in Blender 2.8](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API), the add-on is not compatible with current versions of Blender.